# How to list all AKS with status via CLI (running/stopped)

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cli

I use below statement to list all my aks:

```
az aks list -o table
```

This statement seems not to have information about whether the AKS is running or stopped. I see the field "ProvisioningState" which tells me "Succeeded" for a certain cluster, but this cluster is currently stopped. How do I have to extend above statement to get an additional column which tells me whether the corresponding AKS is running or stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add required columns with the `--query` parameter using JMESPath syntax. For example:

```
$ az aks list --query "[].{Name:name, Power:powerState.code}" -o table
Name                    Power
----------------------  -------
cluster-1               Running
cluster-2               Running
```